# How to avoid Error in load Namespace using R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, htmltools

Am trying to launch a shiny app using the below command.

```
Rscript -e "shiny::runApp('test-app', launch.browser=TRUE)"
```

However, I get an error as shown below

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.4.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.0.9003 is required
Calls: :: ... getNamespace -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

I did check my library folder and see that `htmltools` package is present.

I also tried the below `dependencies=TRUE`

```
install.packages(pkgs,lib = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/data/library",repo = "https://cloud.r-project.org",dependencies=TRUE)
```

Here pkgs is a list containing list of packages that has to be installed.

The problem is same script works in my system but it doesn't work in my colleague's system. How can I resolve this?

Can help me understand what's the issue?

Comment: Update the htmltools package ...

Comment: I tried `install.packages('htmltools')` but it still throws the same error

Comment: @Roland - I thought running `install.packages('htmltools') will always fetch the latest package

Comment: When I type `update.packages()` and try to launch the Shiny app, I also get the same error

Comment: The current version is 0.5.0. The error clearly says that your version is too old.

Comment: Yes, but my question is why is that `update.packages` or` install.packages('htmltools') `doesn't update/intsall the latest one... Aren't those the right commands?

Comment: How about an old and clean disinstall and reinstall? You may have `htmltools` installed in more than one folder (`path.package("htmltools")` to see where R reads it). With the command `.libPaths()` you should see all the possibles places where R saves its libraries. That package may be saved with different versions in more than one folder.

Comment: @Edo - What does it mean when `path.package("htmltools")` returns error like `none of the packages are loaded`

Comment: Actually I have installed this packages in a specific directory which is not in my `libpaths`...

Comment: First, you need to load the package: `library(htmltools)`. `path.package` will show you where R is reading it from.

Comment: How can I make R look at my package from a specific directory (which isn't in my libpaths).

Comment: The directory that I provided above in my post (`lib.loc`) isn't the libpaths

Comment: I guess the issue will be resolved the code looks up at my specific directory...instead of usual libpath. Can you let me know how can it be done? Though I have configured the path in `install.packages` and `update.packages`, the path.package still shows the `libpath`

Comment: Restart R [ctrl + shift + f10] then run `library(htmltools, lib.loc = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/data/library")`. Check the version with `packageVersion("htmltools")`

Comment: however, it's not a clean and shareable solution with your colleagues, because they will have to update your code every time they use it. I'd strongly suggest you to use the R default libraries locations. Or you could add that folder as a possible libpaths [again, I don't suggest that]..

Comment: Hi one quick question. Yes, it was showing 0.4.0... So I deleted it... And download R binaries (zip folder) version 0.5.0 and replaced it...When I type the command `packageVersion("htmltools")`, it still displays the old version which 0.4.0

Comment: Restart R [ctrl + shift + f10]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although Kouadio has the correct answer, I found it difficult to follow those brief instructions, so I'm making them more detailed here.

1. Quit RStudio.
2. Find the RStudio launch icon, either on your desktop or in your Windows Start Menu.
3. Right-click the icon and choose "Run as administrator."  Say yes when prompted that this is really what you want to do.
4. In RStudio, go to the Tools menu and choose Check for Updates.
5. Select all the packages and choose to update them.  Say yes to the relevant prompts.

You should then be able to use the Knit button again, but you probably want to quit RStudio and restart in non-administrative mode before doing so.

Answer (score 3):

I found new solution ,
you need to run rstudio with admin mode for check you update
After all packages are installed
Close Rstudio
Run Rstudio in normal mode .

Comment: Yes, it worked. I just did it now. close your **Rstudio**, then run it as admin. Update or install all needed packages. Now run **Rstudio** normally and knit, all html, word and pdf will build perfectly.